# Does it make sense to call only one `async` method and `await` for it in another `async` method?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

Does it make sense to call only one `async` `private` method and `await` for it in another `async` method?
Example:

```
private async Task<string> ReadMyFileAsync()
{
    var streamReader = new StreamReader(@"c:\myFile.txt")

    return await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync(); // <-- Does it make sense for me here to await for only onething, while the caller of the method ReadMyFileAsync is already an async method?
    // By ignoring that the stream should be disposed...
}

private string ReadMyFile()
{
    var streamReader = new StreamReader(@"c:\myFile.txt")

    return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    // By ignoring that the stream should be disposed...
}

public async void OnFileChangedHandler()
{
    // Some work...
    var myText = await ReadMyFileAsync(); <-- Does it make any difference whether I  called `await ReadMyFileAsync()` or `ReadMyFile()`?

    var someThingElse = await SomeThingElse(...);
    // Some work...
}
```

In the scenario above, what I guess, even if the method `ReadMyFileAsync` was called in its syncronous version (without using `async` and by using `ReadToEnd()` instead of `await ReadToEndAsync()`), it will keep acting the same, because the caller method is an `async` method. Which means in my opinion, this will make sense only if I am trying to read multiple files in paralell (see the following as example), is that right?

```
private async Task<string> ReadMyFileAsync() // <-- This makes sense for me
{
    var streamReader1 = new StreamReader(@"c:\myFile1.txt");
    var streamReader2 = new StreamReader(@"c:\myFile2.txt");
    var streamReader3 = new StreamReader(@"c:\myFile3.txt");

    var myText1Task = streamReader1.ReadToEndAsync();
    var myText2Task = streamReader2.ReadToEndAsync();
    var myText3Task = streamReader3.ReadToEndAsync();

    return await myText1Task + await myText2Task + await myText3Task;

    // By ignoring that the streams should be disposed...
}
```

So the question is simply, in the first block of code, **does it make any difference whether I  called `ReadMyFileAsync` or `ReadMyFile`?**

## Update: The whole question simplified is:

If I am going to await for the async method `ReadMyFileAsync` inside my async method `OnFileChangedHandler`, why would I use `ReadMyFileAsync` over `ReadMyFile`?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand the question. Are you asking if one-line methods makes sense?

Comment: It's an interesting question and my intuition tells me, no, it does not make sense to do that for exactly the reasons you have described. Both awaits will ultimately be waiting on the same work.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, Thank you for your feedback, I added one line at the bottom and added one syncronous version of the method in the first code block. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: *does it make any difference whether I called ReadMyFileAsync or ReadMyFile* benchmark it and find out

Comment: @Liam using StopWatch or do you suggest any other tool or method?

Comment: There are whole books written on this subject. Here's the result of a quick [google search](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/introduction-to-benchmarking-csharp-code-with-benchmark-dot-net) and the good old [Jon Skeet one](https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/benchmark.html)

Comment: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html

Comment: This all highlights the issue with these types of question, you, the OP, want a *use x not y* answer. The reality is that it's much more complicated than that. [nvoigt is the correct answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62772052/542251)

Comment: @Liam I think nvoigt's answer answering a "should I await my async method or should I pass the task along" question. While the question is more "why should I prefer DoXXXAsync instead of DoXXX"

Comment: @MaximKosov I think you are the only one who understood my question completely. Even though thanks for the others' help.

Answer (score 3):

It depends. If you really only call one other method and you have no side effects, then you could just return the `Task` instead of `await`ing it and returning the result wrapped in a task.

However, even in your example, you *have* side effects. You need to `.Dispose` something and you need to know when to do that. So you cannot just return the task, you need to wait until it's finished, then dispose your resources and then return the result of the finished task. Since it's "not that simple" even in your own boiled down example, the answer is: it does make sense. You have to decide case-by-case.

Sometimes you can just pass the task along, then the method does not need to be `async` at all, it just needs to return a `Task` and sometimes you need to do things based on the timing of tasks (i.e. do this only after that other thing is finished) and then you need to use `async` methods because you want to `await` results.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, actually the main point in my case is located in your first line: does it make any difference to call the sycn or async version of the private method (ReadMyFile or ReadMyFileAsync) in my code in the first block? (I added some some code in the first block). I would say no, because the time consumed to finish the work will stay the same. Or am I missing something? Of course ignoring the side effects in my example.

Comment: I added a small update that simplifies the whole question, could you take a look on it please?

Comment: There is a 10 page essay hidden behind my simple answer. Making something return a `Task` that can be awaited has advantages in some scenarios. But if you don't have one of those scenarios, don't complicate your code with unnecessary async/await calls. In other words: if normal works, don't go out of your way to make it async.

Comment: @nvoigt when writing big application it does make sense to use async methods from get go because otherwise you can find yourself in a situation where you need to refactor the whole methods chain to async. Also, modern .net supports async everywhere including cli apps. So it's not that hard at all to just use async everywhere.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you should prefer `async` methods over sync because async methods doesn't block the executing thread. In UI apps it means that UI won't freeze. In Server apps it means that your server will be able to run more concurrent work without starving the threads.

Comment: That is a sweeping genalisation

Comment: But what if the caller method is also async, does it make any difference to use the async version if I only have on async call?

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin you mean what is the difference on calling sync method vs async _inside_ the async function? Well, adding `async ` to your method definition doesn't make your method async. If you have only sync calls inside this method then the whole method will be synchronous.

Comment: @Liam yes, I agree. But I don't see any reasons in using sync method if you _can_ use the async.

Comment: I added a small update that simplifies the whole question, could you take a look on it please?

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin it works differently. Sync method will make the executing thread sleep doing nothing. `await` will schedule a continuation. Thread may do other work while awaiting.

Comment: That is a very broad generalization. The async/await pattern brings a lot of it's own difficulties and there is no point in bringing the added complexity to your application, if simple synchronous calls work for your case.

Comment: Using async is not difficult at all in the modern .net. Nowadays every modern project structure supports or even enforces async everywhere.

Comment: The only situation where I'd prefer sync over async is the legacy project where you need to refactor too much for async.

Comment: You assumption there is that `async` is free. It's not. Async has a cost in thread synchonisation. If you doing CPU bound processing where the CPU is busy this thread utilisation cost simply makes your code slower. async/await is the right answer for IO bound operations. But you cannot simply state *use async*. The [actual answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62772052/542251) is, it depends

Comment: @Liam well, you don't just randomly create async methods right? Usually you create an async method if you call async methods inside it. Usually that means that you call IO bound operations inside your method. I don't think that cost of synchronisation will outhweight the cost of using the FS (the question was about `ReadToEnd`). So, I totally agree that "it depends". But 99% of cases you should use async where possible. Unless you can prove it's not efficient using the profiler.

Comment: Upvoted because it highlights the core difference between calling a synchronous versus awaiting an asynchronous method. You could, however, remove the "prefer" statement that could trigger some valid disagreements, and just state the differences between the two approaches.